# mb_convert_case deleting Unicode characters?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

My code:

```
echo mb_convert_case('Björk Guðmundsdóttir', MB_CASE_UPPER, 'UTF-8');
echo mb_convert_case('Björk Guðmundsdóttir', MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8');
```

and the output:

```
BJRK GUMUNDSDTTIR
bjrk gumundsdttir
```

Some characters were deleted. Anyone know why?

**UPDATE 1:**

I noticed that my PHP file was note saved as UTF-8. So, I saved it as UTF-8 and ran the code again. My new results:

```
BJÃ–RK GUÃMUNDSDÃ“TTIR
bjÃ¶rk guÃ°mundsdÃ³ttir
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I guess the problem was just that it was being displayed weird in the browser. Solved by adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue, have you verified that the text removed is a member of the UTF-8 family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure your editor is set to UTF-8 without BOM, then you must make sure that the text you passed to the function is actually UTF-8, since that is what you specified as the third argument. Then it should work

EDIT: You might also want to check that your browser is interpreting the characters correctly and make sure the page is setting the content-type, using either a `<meta>` tag or PHPs [header()](http://www.php.net/header)

Comment: Those characters are UTF-8, right? I'm using Zend Studio and think I have it set to UTF-8 properly. Still not working.